# Problem with adding numbers to a string in a while loop Python

Tags: python, loops

I need to generate a list of items with number. For example:

```
item-1
item-2
item-3
..
item 246234
```

I'm trying to solve it with a while loop. Here is my code:

```
pages = []
page = 'item-'
nr = 1
last = 10
while nr <= last
    page = page + str(nr)
    pages.append(page)
    nr += 1
```

But instead of desired result I got:

```
item-1
item-12
item-123
item-1234
and so on
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is not a typical use for a while loop. While you can make it work, I would highly suggest one of the other solutions posted below not using while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `page` accumulates numbers in each iteration. Use another variable name inside the loop:

```
while nr <= last
    pageX = page + str(nr)
    pages.append(pageX)
    nr += 1
```

Or add the page directly to the list, with no intermediate variable:

```
while nr <= last:
    pages.append(page + str(nr))
    nr += 1
```

Or use a `for` loop so you don't have to check and increment the number yourself:

```
for nr in range(1, last+1):
    pages.append(page + str(nr))
```

Or a list comprehension to make the whole code shorter and (IMHO) more readable:

```
pages = ["item-" + str(nr) for nr in range(1, last+1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say `page = ...` you're overwriting the original "template" that you use every time. Just use a different variable:

```
while nr <= last:
    current_page = page + str(nr)
    pages.append(current_page)
    nr += 1
```

Incidentally, this is much more clearly expressed in idiomatic python as follows:

```
pages = [f"item-{i}" for i in range(1, 11)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pythonic way:

```
pages = ['item-'+str(nr) for nr in range(1, last+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way, loop till the last number of pages and append to list creating each page with the current index:

```
pages=[]
pagex = "item-"
for i in range(1,last+1):
    page = pagex + str(i)
    pages.append(page)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you added an explanation. Use [edit] to annotate the answer.